# R is not recognizing levels of a factor as the same. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset which provides the schooling of individuals, and I'm trying to extract the place an individual received their Bachelor's degree from. These were imported as factors (because I think it'd be easier to visualize the data later).

The dataset is structured such that there is the individual (id), and then School1, Degree1, School2, Degree2, School3, Degree3. These are all factor variables. For 90% of people, School1 is the undergraduate institution, but because some people in the data have Associate's degrees, it might be School2 or School 3.

I'm using dplyr to create a variable, undergrad, that takes the value of the School if the Degree was a Bachelor's Degree.

```r
structure(list(nid = c(1394646L, 1393931L, 1376976L, 1376981L
), School1 = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Brooklyn Law School", 
"Brown University", "Cornell University", "Washington College (now Washington and Jefferson College)"
), class = "factor"), Degree1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("B.A.", "LL.B."), class = "factor"), School2 = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("", "Read law", "Yale Law School"), class = "factor"), 
    Degree2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
    "J.D."), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(undergrad=case_when(
                                  Degree1=="B.A." ~ School1,
                                  Degree1.=="B.S." ~ School1
                                  ))
```

This generally works well.

However, when I move to the second school, there are a few problems. For one, even though I've written that the variable undergrad should keep its value from the previous code, for some of the observations, it's overwritten (not sure why). I'm not sure whether this has to do with the last line and somehow I'm not meeting the requirements of the logical vector.

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(undergrad=case_when(
                 (Degree2=="B.A." & is.na(undergrad))  ~ School2,
                 (Degree2=="B.S." & is.na(undergrad)) ~ School2,
                  TRUE ~ undergrad
))
```

Another way I've tried this is to import the schools and degrees as strings (characters) rather than factors. This works, but then another problem I run into is that after all is said and done, I want to convert it back into a factor. However, R doesn't recognize that some of the schools are the same, and so I get two instances of a school, like Harvard, rather than it counting as one level.

Is there any way for R to recognize this?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to, but dput is being weird right now and outputting all the rows, even when I've only selected a subset.

Comment: would `dput(droplevels(head(df1)))` is big

Comment: Thanks. That made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your first problem, I think you can do all of it in a single pass:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(undergrad = case_when(Degree1 %in% c("B.A.", "B.S.") ~ School1,
                               Degree2 %in% c("B.A.", "B.S.") ~ School2))
```

One problem with this approach would be if you have any students who have 2 bachelors from 2 institutions. This strikes me as really unlikely, but if it did happen you would only assign the second school to them. If that is a problem, you could solve that this way:

```
df1 %<>%
  mutate(undergrad = case_when(Degree1 %in% c("B.A.", "B.S.") ~ School1,
                               (Degree2 %in% c("B.A.", "B.S.") & 
                                  !Degree1 %in% c("B.A.", "B.S.")) ~ School2))
```

Also note that in the second example I switched to the two-way pipe from `magrittr` as a purely stylistic choice.

As far as your second question goes, there is no easy solution. No programming language can inherently tell that "Harvard" and "Harvard University" and "Harvard U" all refer to the same thing. You could try some fuzzy matching (using the Levenshtein distance, for example) to generate a new name variable, but this will probably be imperfect.

That said, I'm not sure I understand why you only have this problem if you import as character and then convert to a factor. The underlying data is a string. In both cases R is going to treat any differences in strings as different levels in a factor, regardless of when that conversion is performed.

Comment: So the schools, character wise, are the same. They're both Harvard University, but when I analyze the levels of the new factor I've created, it recognizes them as separate levels.

Comment: My best guess would be that there is some kind of difference between the strings. If you import as a character and then run unique(df1$School1) do you also get two Harvards? Also, what kind of file is the data stored as and how are you importing it in both cases?

Comment: Another follow up here. Th code above worked, but I was wondering if you had any suggestions for when you want a changed input?

I have a case in which some people just "read" and I'd like that annotated. So far, I have School1=="Read" ~ as.factor("Read") as the code but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - can you clarify what you want the output to be?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new factor level that as "Read" rather than a pre-established level of a factor.